# Unnecessary JARs in Eclipse project - potential problems?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar

I have 5-6 projects in my workspace, many of which are interdependent.

I usually just put all possible JARs from other projects `lib` dir into the build path of the current project, without bothering to check which is necessary for the build.

Can this approach cause problems, given that there are some few dozens of JARs in each project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The more code you have, the more bugs there are
- Your project is bigger than it should be.
- It could lead to problems if there are classes named the same, and Eclipse automatically puts the wrong imports.
- Builds will take longer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @m0skit0 and can add into continuation that you should do you best effort to remove libraries you do not really use.

It may be very difficult to do manually. So, better way is to use automatic dependencies management. Maven and Gradle do this job perfectly. You just mention the first level dependencies (that you should know). They care about the second, third etc. level dependencies. You never update your `lib` directory. The build tool updates your local repository automatically.

Answer (score 0):

By interdependent, I hope you don't mean that you have circular dependencies. This would be a big NO!

If your dependencies are not cyclic, then I don't see any problem. You'll need all those jars in the runtime classpath anyway to run the program. What you might want to avoid is to have some direct dependencies in the code of project A to a library "old_library_still_needed_by_project_B_but_that_should_not_be_used_anymore.jar" used by project B, but there are static Java code analysis tools for this (which can check the some classes or packages are never used inside a project source code), like CheckStyle and PMD.